# jQuery .val() ignoring trailing decimal points

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am currently working on limiting the allowed input in a numeric text field. I check the length of the value of the input field, if it is >= to the maxlength attribute, don't input anything.

```
$('input[maxlength]').on('keyup', '', null, function(event) {
    var ref = $(this),
        val = ref.val();
    if ( val.length >= this.maxLength && event.which != 8){
        return false;
    }
}
```

However, if the currently value of the field ends in a decimal (eg "4."), then the val() method returns "4", which throws off the whole process. How can I read the contents of the input field while including the trailing decimal points?

http://jsfiddle.net/n3fmw1mw/329/ (Type in '4.' and you'll see what I'm talking about.)

EDIT: I've tried something from Mr. Hill's suggestion and now I have this

```
$('input[maxlength]').on('keydown', '', null, function(event) { //enforce maxlength on all inputs, not just text inputs
    var ref = $(this);
    ref.attr('type','text');
    var val = ref.val();

    if ( val.length >= this.maxLength  && event.which != 8){
        ref.attr('type','number');          
        return false;
    }
    ref.attr('type','number');   
});
```

But now nothing is being inserted into my text box, even if debugging and seeing that we aren't returning false.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The decimal is being dropped because your input type is number. Set your input type to text.

```
<input type="text" id="textbox1"/>
```

Here's [a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesHill/L6dqzosj/).

**EDIT**

Based on your new requirement of not being able to change the source, the code below should get you pointed in the right direction.

jQuery does not allow you to change the type of an element. To do it, you must remove the element and add one of the correct type in its place. The code below does just that.

**Note:** In an effort to make the code more reusable, I added a class to your element and then edited all elements with that particular class.

```
// Add class to identify that element type needs changed
$("#textbox1").addClass("numberToText");

// Swap number type input with text
$('.numberToText').each(function() {
  $("<input type='text' />").attr({
    id: this.id,
    name: this.name,
    value: this.value
  }).insertBefore(this);
}).remove();

$("#textbox1").keyup(function() {
  $('#log').append("Value: " + $('#textbox1').val() + '<br/>');
});

$(".button").click(function() {
  $('#log').append("Value: " + $('#textbox1').val());
})
```

Here's [a working fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesHill/nhzcn4m6/)

Comment: I can't change the input type at the source, so I tried manually changing it during the keydown event (see my edit). Now nothing is being put into the text field when I enter characters.

Comment: @MicrosoftExcel, you can't change the input type with jQuery. Give me a second to update my answer.

Comment: Sadly, not really. I can't change the type of input because both the web and mobile validation rely on the type for their validation. I ended up checking the steps attribute of the input field, and if it's an int, then don't allow decimals to be input. This handled the majority of cases. I appreciate your help though, it helped me circle in on a solution. I wouldn't have known that the input type is what was dropping the trailing decimal. I'm going to go ahead and accept this answer, it would be right call in the majority of other cases of this problem.